# Handle error in Lightning Component using Lightning Data Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, error-messages, lightning-data-service

I am having a lightning component that uses the Lightning Data services. The component is like below which has a button which when clicking on it changes the case status to Closed.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >
<aura:attribute name="loaded" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading..." class="{!(v.loaded? 'slds-show': 'slds-hide')}" />
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" 
        objectApiName="Case" 
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
        onerror="{!c.handleError}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
         <!--<lightning:spinner aura:id="spinner" variant="brand" /> -->
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="statusInput" fieldName="Status" class="slds-hide" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Close Case(LDS)" />
 </lightning:recordEditForm>    
</aura:component>
```

And controller

```
({
    handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded',true);
        event.preventDefault();      
        var fields = event.getParam('fields');
        fields.Status = 'Closed';
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fields)); 
        component.find('form').submit(fields); 
        
    },
    
    handleError: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded',false);
        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
        .setParams({
            type: 'error',
            mode: 'pester',
            message: 'Case cannot be closed, please verify the required fields like Category are filled !!' }).fire();  
    },
    
    handleSuccess: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.loaded',false);
            $A.get("e.force:showToast")
            .setParams({
            type: 'success',
            message: 'Case is closed!',
            mode: 'pester'
            })
        .fire();
    }
})
```

I am currently in the handleError hard coding the error message but I am trying to get the errors from the Validation/ if something goes wrong instead of hard coding the errors. I tried to get the error

```
    var error = event.getParams();
    // Get the error message
    var errorMessage = event.getParam("message");
```

and give it in the message it just gives the generic error message in the toast like
[image]
instead I should be getting the validation error

`A Category is required to close the case.`

How to get the Validation errors in to the lightning component from the Lightning Data Services.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `event.getParams();`. The property that hold the error message you're seeking depends on the location of the error defined in your validation rule.

If the error is to appear on a field, the error messages can be found in `event.getParam('output').fieldErrors` - an object of field errors.

Example:

```
const fieldErrors = event.getParam('output').fieldErrors;
const separator = ' ';

let message = Object.values(fieldErrors).map(field => {
    return field.map(error => error.message).join(separator);
}).join(separator);

$A.get("e.force:showToast").setParams({
    type: 'error',
    mode: 'pester',
    message: message 
}).fire();
```

If the error is to appear on the top of the page, the error message can be found in `event.getParam('detail')` or `event.getParam('output').errors` - an array of errors.

Comment: I tried using event.getParam('output').errors and event.getParam('detail') but I dont see any error on the toast

Comment: Tried all the three options but array is all empty I see no error messages

Comment: What do you get in the console when you `console.log(event.getParams())`?

Comment: Proxy {}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false

Comment: There is no fields in the <lightning:recordEditForm> it just the button, which is when is clicked it tries to update the record status.

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.getParams())));` to read the contents of the Proxy object.

Comment: I added the screenshot of the JSON

Comment: Great, I'll edit my answer with an approach to get the messages showing inside your toast.

Comment: I have similar question with the Lightning Data services https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320954/replace-the-lightning-components-which-uses-apex-to-lightning-data-service can you please help me with it

Answer (score 1):

`onerror` is a built-in event of `lightning:recordEditForm`. So to read the events you must use the event like `var err = event.getParam("error");`. This returns an object which has

- *message*: General description of error.
- *detail*: Description of error details, if any.
- *output*: Record exception errors with errors and fieldErrors properties. For example, to return the error details when a required field is missing, use event.getParam("output").fieldErrors.
- *error*: Returns the status code via status and statusText properties.

Alternatively you can consider using `<lightning:messages/>` in the component which will automatically display the errors. lightning:messages displays the message, and the detail or fieldErrors record exception message if it's available.

You can find more details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation)

Comment: Can you please help me how to use the <lightning:messages/> here

Comment: Place `<lightning:messages/>` as a direct child, between your opening `<lightning:recordEditForm>` and closing `</lightning:recordEditForm>` tag. However this will show the error message inline rather than as a floating toast.

Comment: @akiradev Yes I tried this <lightning:messages/> and dont help with my component