# Replace the Lightning Components which uses Apex to Lightning Data Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service

I currently have the lightning component which updates some of the fields on the Case record  and also inserts the Case Comment and associates to the case where the fields are updated through the Apex Class like below

```
                record.OwnerId = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
                record.RecordTypeId = 'yyyyyyyyy';
                record.Status = 'Transferred';
                QueueName = 'XYZ Queue';
                
                 update record; 
                
                String commentBody = 'Passing to '+ QueueName +' for action.';
                CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(ParentId = record.Id,CommentBody = commentBody, IsPublished = false);
                insert cc;
```

I want this to be done through the LDS and in the controller I am doing like

```
  handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();      
    var fields = event.getParam('fields');
    fields.Status = 'Transferred';
    fields.OwnerId = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    fields.RecordTypeId = 'yyyyyyyyy';
    console.log(JSON.stringify(fields)); 
    component.find('form').submit(fields); 

    var QueueName = 'XYZ Queue';       

   /// Not sure how to create a Case comment record and associate with the Case record
  }
```

Can anyone please suggest me if we can create the other record and associate it with them. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: As per the documentation, CaseComment Object is not supported by the User Interface API.

Supported Objects - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm

Comment: @HReddy Does that mean we cannot create Comments using the LightningData Services